# Convergence of sums over non-trivial zeros of $\zeta (s)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, riemann-zeta

The convergence of this particular type of sums over non-trivial zeros of the zeta function has been investigated:
$$\sum_{\rho}\frac{1}{\rho}=1+\frac{1}{2}\gamma -\frac{1}{2}\ln 4\pi ,$$
$$\sum_{\rho}\frac{1}{\rho ^2}=1+\gamma ^2-\frac{1}{8}\pi ^2+2\gamma _1 ,$$
$$\sum_{\rho}\frac{1}{\rho ^3}=1+\gamma ^3+3\gamma\gamma _1 +\frac{3}{2}\gamma _2 -\frac{7}{8}\zeta (3),$$
($\gamma _n$ are Stieltjes constants) and so on.

Has the convergence of another "type" of sums over the non-trivial zeros been investigated, or are the $\rho ^{-k}$ sums the only ones? For example, using the existing knowledge about these sums, could the convergence of $$\sum_{\rho}e^{\rho x}$$ be determined?

Maybe you could refer me to some books or another sources (if some exist) where there is a broader discussion of convergence of such sums apart from the $\rho ^{-k}$ ones (and *Riemann's explicit formula*).

Comment: You surely are aware of [Riemann's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Explicit_formulae_for_L-functions#Riemann's_explicit_formula), which involves the logarithmic integral, yes?

Comment: Well yes, I think it's obvious. Nevertheless, I'll add it to the question.